# Ubuntu Server 18.04 -Configuring the Static Ip I had lost the dhcp entries generated by the system

Tags: networking, server

In the process configuring Static Ip I lost the dhcp entries generated by the system because I overwritten with Static entry that is not working. This is the error: ***"Invalid YAML at /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml line 8 column 16: mapping values are not allowed in this context"***

```
network: 
 version: 2 
 renderer: 
 networkd ethernets: 
   enp0s1: 
    dhcp4: no 
    addresses: [192.168.0.100/24] 
    gateway4: 192.168.0.1 
    nameservers:  
      addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your config enclosed in triple single quotes so that we can see the actual formatting? I think you are missing indent there but hard to judge from your output

It should be something like

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s1:
      dhcp4: no 
      addresses: [192.168.0.100/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1 
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Edit after Thomas's comment - if your formatting is as Thomas's edit shows, then you have an error in renderer line.

Comment: ... or, we can just go into the post and edit it and apply code formatting.  Which is done now :)  However, that invalidates this answer as it currently stands, because this no longer answers the question ;)

Comment: Assuming you formatted it the way Ofinet has it on the system (I was not brave enough to make such assumption), then the answer is still valid as it shows how it should be and renderer line stands out, making invalid yaml.